# SharePoint REST API TimeCreated and TimeLastModified properties are different even if a file wasn't modified

Tags: onedrive, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I uploaded a file to a user's OneDrive and than I used SharePoint REST API to fetch the file information. I used the following endpoint:

```
https://*-my.sharepoint.com/personal/*/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='*file-path*')/
```

The response I got:

```
{
    *
    "TimeCreated": "2019-12-09T09:42:39Z",
    "TimeLastModified": "2019-12-09T09:42:41Z",
    *
}
```

As you can see the *TimeCreated* and *TimeLastModified* differ by 2 seconds, however, I didn't touch the file after it was uploaded. Can someone explain why do I see such a difference?

Comment: Can you check versioning for that specific file? Based on that you can figure out what other action is processed after creation otherwise `TimeLastModified` will be null ideally if no updatetion is made.